# How can I start the bullets shooting by script once the shooting animation start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the editor in the animator I have a state with animation Aiming Sniper Rifle that animate a shooting in a loop. I'm not sure if it's right but I added a new parameter name Shooting type bool. And added it as true to the transition :

[image: Animator and transition]

To the bullet I added a Rigidbody and the shooting script :

[image: Bullet]

And the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectile;

    private void Update()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 10);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that it will start shooting bullets nonstop once the shooting animation(Aiming Sniper Rifle) start.

I thought that I will need the new shooting bool parameter for that but not sure how to use it with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you can add another parameter in the animator that is set to true when the animation starts and to false when it finishes. To get this parameter in the code you can use `anim.GetBool("<name of the parameter>");`, where anim is a Animator variable that points to the main player animator.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetBool.html

Comment: If the my answer brought a solution to your question please mark as accepted, it helps me to help more people, too. Thanks 

Comment: I marked it as accepted but also answered my own one with more details of what I did. Do you think I did it right ?

Comment: Yes! You're in the right path. Hope your game/studies turn out great!

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution.

In the editor in the Animator in the transition I'm using the parameter shooting and set it to false in the Conditions :

[image: Conditions]

Then in the script in the Start I'm setting the parameter to true and then in the Update checking if it's true :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectile;
    public Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
        {
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 10, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

And it's start shooting once the shooting animation start.